# Connection refused - despite iptables rule is accept and port is open

Tags: iptables

I am trying to setup an ssh service.  I am behind a residential router, and connecting to the desktop on a laptop computer.  I use the the local IP of the desktop (192.1 ...) for address.

The server is Ubuntu Lucid and I have the openssh service running.  Checking with `netstat antlp |grep LISTEN` shows port 22 is listening.  iptables entry (`sudo iptables -L`) shows incoming traffic on port 22 is open (accept anywhere/anywhere).

On the laptop, when I try `nc  -z ip 22 -v`, I get connection refused error no matter how many times I tried with different interval.  Really baffled and don't know what else could be the reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: post your iptables rules as you may have an earlier rule rejecting traffic.

Comment: Why don't you just use `ssh -l <user> <IP>` to test the connection instead of Netcat?

Comment: @CijcoSistems `ssh -vvv user@ip` is better ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I think it's too much verbose, but I agree the user@ip syntax looks better :P

Comment: can never be too verbose with refused connections ;) . My guess is still an earlier iptables rule rejecting the connection.

Comment: OK, sorry, it's not exactly for an SSH service (thought it's easier to explain this way) so that's why netcat is used.  I am trying to setup a dameon server listening to port X .  It works on localhost, but I can't get it to run remotely.

Comment: Maybe you are listening on the wrong interface. Just to be sure, are you trying to access inside your network or from outside? Remember to enable NAT (or DMZ) if you are outside.

Comment: Is there something really listening the port?

Comment: Yes, netstat antlp|grep LISTEN shows server is on. locally it works too.  so it is definitely up and running. the problem is remotely I can't reach it.  I blanked the entire iptables rule set and it didn't work either.   -- Also, I am trying to connect over LAN, no need for NAT. I can ping the ip, but nc gives out the error "connection refused".     Can you elaborate about listening on the wrong interface ?

Comment: Here is something that maybe relevant. when I do nc on localhost, this is what I get: nc: connect to localhost port xxxx (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to localhost xxxx port [tcp/*] succeeded!

Comment: By _listening on the wrong interface_ I meant the process is bound to one interface or IP (127.0.0.1) but you are trying to connect to another one (192.168.x.y). Even the host machine is the same, you can reach it from different places. This is the IP my `netstat -n -l` shows for ssh: 0.0.0.0:22, it tells me the process is listening on port 22, any available interface. But for the DNS (Bind) there are two entries: 127.0.0.1:53 and 192.168.x.y:53. Make sure your process is _not only_ listening on 127.0.0.1:22.